# Cancel TextBox input on validation errors

Tags: wpf, validation, textbox

The standard behavior in TextBoxes when a input string is not valid is to show a red square (for example user introduces a letter in numeric TextBox). This happens when TextBox loses focus.

I want implement this behavior:

- The textBox loses focus.
- TextBox do internal validation (date, numeric, etc).
- If input user string is not valid, old value is restored and TextBox don't show any error.

Answer (score 0):

you have an exemple of validation in textbox here in this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/690130/Simple-Validation-in-WPF

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="validationErrorTemplate">
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" 
            DockPanel.Dock="Top">!</TextBlock>
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder 
           x:Name="ErrorAdorner"
        ></AdornedElementPlaceholder>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate> 




 public class NameValidator : ValidationRule
    {
        public override ValidationResult Validate
          (object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return new ValidationResult(false, "value cannot be empty.");
            else
            {
                if (value.ToString().Length > 3)
                    return new ValidationResult
                    (false, "Name cannot be more than 3 characters long.");
            }
            return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
        }
    }


<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Name="textBox1" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" 
              Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationErrorTemplate}"
         >
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Name" Mode="TwoWay" 
        UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:NameValidator></local:NameValidator>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverting to the old value is quite easy if you use MVVM. In your ViewModel's prop setter you can simply not set the new value to the model if it's invalid and invoke `PropertyChanged` instead. This will tell the bound view element to call your property getter, which will return the old value and thus revert the view element's content to the old value.

Example (validating that user input is an `int` value):

```
public string Number
{
    get { return _model.Number.ToString(); }
    set
    {
        if (_model.Number.ToString() != value)
        {
            int number;
            if (int.TryParse(value, out number))
            {
                _model.Number = number;
            }

            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Number));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That works fine for validations in viewmodel. The problem here is when user introduces an invalid date string and the property in ViewModel is DateTime. TextBox do the internal validation itself and shows the error; textbox don't do the binding to viewmodel because it can't convert the string to DateTime and the wrong date string remains in it.